# What is the difference between GUI and UI?

Tags: user-interface

What is the difference between GUI = Graphical User Interface and UI = User Interface?

Comment: There is no categorical difference other than the meanings of the words. I guess the UI of a bicycle is the pedals. Not sure what the point of the question is. Should be Community Wiki

Answer (score 78, accepted):

GUI is "graphical user interface" and UI is just "user interface." GUI is a subset of UI. UI can include non-graphical interfaces such as screen readers or command line interfaces which aren't considered GUI.

Comment: Also, the opposite of GUI is CLI - Command Line Interface. At least until mind readers become commercial.

Comment: The definition of something many times depends on the context. Although GUI is a subset of UI, sometimes GUI and UI are used interchangeably, and you might hear some engineers saying "on the CLI or on the UI?", altough CLI is a UI!

Comment: UI includes any user interface. Examples of input user interfaces are keyboard, mouse, touch screen, accelerometer, etc. Examples of output user interfaces are screen, speakers, tactile feedback, LEDs, etc. Nowadays, however, most people refer to GUI as simply UI. And thus, UI-related jobs are mostly graphic design related.

Comment: Or even TUI / Text User Interface

Answer (score 23):

Keyword - Graphical.

**User Interface**

In the industrial design field of human-machine interaction, the user interface is (a place) where interaction between humans and machines occurs. The goal of interaction between a human and a machine at the user interface is effective operation and control of the machine, and feedback from the machine which aids the operator in making operational decisions. Examples of this broad concept of user interfaces include the interactive aspects of computer operating systems, hand tools, heavy machinery operator controls. and process controls. The design considerations applicable when creating user interfaces are related to or involve such disciplines as ergonomics  and psychology.

A user interface is the system by which people (users) interact with a machine. The user interface includes hardware (physical) and software (logical) components. User interfaces exist for various systems, and provide a means of:

```
* Input, allowing the users to manipulate a system, and/or
* Output, allowing the system to indicate the effects of the users' manipulation.
```

**Graphical User Interface**

A graphical user interface (GUI) (sometimes pronounced gooey[1]) is a type of user interface item that allows people to interact with programs in more ways than typing such as computers; hand-held devices such as MP3 players, portable media players or gaming devices; household appliances and office equipment with images rather than text commands. ***A GUI offers graphical icons, and visual indicators, as opposed to text-based interfaces, typed command labels or text navigation to fully represent the information and actions available to a user***. The actions are usually performed through direct manipulation of the graphical elements.

There are lots of other types of User Interfaces.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface#Types

Source - Wikipedia

Answer (score 10):

A "G".

That "G" stands for "graphic" - not all user interfaces are graphic. Some programs have textual interfaces. Some watch movements of your retinas, or talk to you in audible Chinese, or... or....

Answer (score 6):

The difference between a TUI and a GUI is:

1. TUI is Textual User Interface that means falls in between the Command Line and Graphical User Interfaces.
2. GUI is Graphical User Interface means, wherein graphical objects such as icons, toolbars, and menus are used to perform an action.

Thank you! :) <3 :)

Answer (score 2):

there are different types of UI's than just GUI's.  GUI usually refers to WIMP style interfaces: windows, icons, menus, pointer. There's also CLI or command line interface, and ZUI or zooming interface, or Touch Screen interfaces, or hardware interfaces (like game controllers) etc... etc...

Comment: That's kind of like asking how many types of people there are. It all depends on how you label things. You might bunch up thin-client GUI and fat-client GUI under GUI, or you might not. You might consider a speech recognition interface a kind of audio interface, or you might not.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing - just jargon.  GUI = Graphical User Interface, UI = User Interface.  You can use them interchangeably.

Comment: GUI = Graphical User Interface, UI = User Interface that i already know. but isn't there any technical difference?

Comment: Oh come on zealots...  it's all by convention.  99% of industry people use the two terms interchangeably.  With modern OS's - they're all 'graphical', but that doesn't make using the term UI incorrect.

Clearly I need to stay away from these subjective questions.

Comment: Nowadays in most cases UI is GUI, but not always and therefore I see no reason to post false information. Of course UI is not in any way incorrect since all GUIs are UIs as well. However, you can't go around calling all UIs GUIs. There are lots of text-based UIs around, especially in the Linux world.

Answer (score 0):

There is no major difference(high level) between them but if you want some points to explain the 2 you can refer the below link 
UI can just be any command line interface or a simple text input/output screen GUI would mean more usser friendly.

An explanation can be as below.
"The UI is that part of the machine you use to control the machine and it sometimes has instruments to inform you about the status of the machine. For example an excavator can be controlled by several handles to dig, but could also give information about how many oil is left or at what temperate the engine is running. It is the central point of control and information.

The graphic user interface is where you control the machine in a graphical environment. Usually you control a computer by keyboard and mouse and you see all information on a screen. You see what your input is (what you want to control) and what the output is (the information the computer gives back) all on screen. 
"
The link is below.
http://toostep.com/question/what-difference-between-gui-and-ui

Comment: strictly speaking, there IS a difference. Graphical user interfaces have graphics, textual user interfaces have text. a textual user interface is still a UI but is NOT a GUI.

Comment: This is subjective but there is a difference that the link indicates but if you want just a one word or one line answer you can very well say there is no difference. However if this is asked in an interview you can explain the differences. That is what i mean.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if I did it would be because of your opening line... you explain your way out of it, but initially you're false.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring - What we should call to web designs? Are all web designs GUIs or UIs?

Comment: Technically, neither. "Web designs" are "Web-based user interfaces or web user interfaces (WUI)"

Comment: But to be honest, all we ever use for web-apps is UI. My clients know we're web developers.